# Change in Json Elements causing error in code

Tags: java, parsing, gson

I've finally got my code to start parsing but it seems push out errors when ever I reach certain parts of the Json. For some reason some elements within the Json are different from similarly named elements. API I'm using: http://api.nobelprize.org/v1/laureate.json?

for Example: normal element

```
"year": "someYear",
 "category": "someCategory",
"share": "someint",
"motivation": "\"someMotivation\"",
"affiliations": [
                 {
                  "name": "SomeName",
                  "city": "someCity",
                  "country": "SomeCountry"
                 }
                ]
```

Element later in json string causing errors

```
"year": "someYear",
 "category": "someCategory",
"share": "someint",
"motivation": "\"someMotivation\"",
"affiliations": [
                  []
                ]
```

For some reason the API places an empty list within the affiliations element which is causing errors.

My current class for affiliations looks like this:

```
public class Affiliations {
    String name;
    String city;
    String country;
}
```

Error I'm getting:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY
```

Comment: Their API is pretty terrible, unless there's some special meaning to an empty array within `affiliations`. You'll need a custom deserializer for that.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm stuck with using it, and I don't think there's any reason to include a empty array instead of null. But because of that it's breaking my code. Do you have any idea how i would write the deserializer for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That JSON is... unfortunate. You can create a customer JsonDeserializer, but it still has to return *something* for Affiliations.

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String json = "{ \"name\": \"William Shakespeare\", \"affiliations\": [ { \"name\": \"Globe Theatre\" }, [] ] }";
        final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .registerTypeAdapter(Affiliation.class, new AffiliationDeserializer())
                .create();
        final Laureate laureate = gson.fromJson(json, Laureate.class);
        System.out.println(laureate);

    }

    private static class Laureate {
        String name;
        List<Affiliation> affiliations;

        public Laureate(final String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String toString() {
            return "Laureate[name=" + name + ", affiliations=" + affiliations + "]";
        }
    }

    private static class Affiliation {
        String name;

        public String toString() {
            return "Affiliation[name=" + name +"]";
        }
    }

    private static class AffiliationDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Affiliation> {
        // this innerGson doesn't have AffiliationDeserializer registered, 
        // so it won't get stuck in an infinite loop
        private static final Gson innerGson = new Gson();

        @Override
        public Affiliation deserialize(final JsonElement json, final Type typeOfT,
                                       final JsonDeserializationContext context)
        throws JsonParseException {
            if (json.isJsonObject()) {
                return innerGson.fromJson(json, Affiliation.class);
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
Laureate[name=William Shakespeare, affiliations=[Affiliation[name=Globe Theatre], null]]
```

With this, your list of affiliations has a null in it, which is bad, but a step in the right direction - you can potentially clean these up post-deserialization.

Comment: This will most likely fix my problem, but for some reason I always get errors when it comes to the implementing and overriding the deserializer. I seem to get this as and error: ```AffiliationDeserializer is not abstract and does not override abstract method deserialize(JsonElement,Type,JsonDeserializationContext) in JsonDeserializer``` and ```method does not override or implement a method from a supertype``` on the @Override.

Comment: Just fixed it, it seems that I auto imported something that kept breaking it. Here are the correct imports ```import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.JsonDeserializationContext;
import com.google.gson.JsonDeserializer;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonParseException;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;``` and the import that gave me the error ```import java.lang.ProcessBuilder.Redirect.Type;```